# Duplicating Document Libraries

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, document-library

Is there a way to do this in MOSS 2007?

Instead of manually creating the same type of document library with a different name, I'd like to use a shortcut -if exists- to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save your existing library as a template and then create a new instance from that template. If the altogether size is less than 20MB, you can even include the library contents.

Comment: How can I save a library as a template? I'd be appreciated if you could give further directions.

Comment: In list settings under permission and management you can select "save list as a template". When you do this, an STP file containing the list template (and content if you selected it) will be added to the list template gallery. This list is accessible through Site Actions > Site Settings > Galleries > List Templates. If you need to add this template to another site collection it can either be uploaded through the new SC list template gallery or using STSADM -o addtemplate command.
BE AWARE that lists that are created using STP templates will become unghosted and hence hard to change later

Comment: BTW, this doesn't work in Publishing site templates.. so if the save list as template is not there, thats probably why.